# Webpack 2: Resolving via lookup chain for given paths

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to upgrade to webpack 2 and got stuck on resolving.

In my webpack 1 configuration I got the case that I wanted to look up loaders in `node_modules` folders in several locations and their parents (basically like CommonJS resolving does).

The related part of configuration was like this:

```js
// Location: /project/webpack.config.js
{
  resolveLoaders: {
    root: [ '/project/sub-1/sub-1-1', '/project/sub-2' ]
  }
}
```

This made sure that webpack looked for the loader in (amongst others):

- `/project/sub-1/sub-1-1/node_modules`
- `/project/sub-1/node_modules`
- `/project/sub-2/node_modules`

Now that the `root` option is [gone](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#resolve-root-resolve-fallback-resolve-modulesdirectories) in webpack 2 I fail to reproduce this behaviour.

Reading the webpack 2 documentation, the closest match to what I had before was to use relative paths (to retain the lookup in parent directories) in the new `modules` array.

I tried this:

```js
// Location: /project/webpack.config.js
{
  resolveLoaders: {
    modules: [ './sub-1/sub-1-1', './sub-2', 'node_modules' ]
  }
}
```

But webpack tells me it cannot resolve the loader.

Having tried out some different paths, I now assume that the resolver—given those relative paths—looks for the loader in `./sub-1/sub-1-1` and `./sub-1` directly instead of a `node_modules` folder inside. But that's not what I want it to do.

So: Is there any way to rebuild the webpack 1 behaviour with sane configuration options or do I really have to create an array with my paths (given that they're not static and I don't have control over them) and all their parent folders appending `/node_modules` to each?

```js
{
  resolveLoaders: {
    modules: [
      '/project/sub-1/sub-1-1/node_modules',
      '/project/sub-1/node_modules',
      '/project/sub-2/node_modules',
      '/project/node_modules',
      '/node_modules'
    ]
  }
}
```

This seems like a bunch of unneccessary work to me.